# How to use primefaces and nvd3 together

Tags: primefaces, charts, nvd3.js

I'd like to use the nvd3.js  charts in my jsf+primefaces application.
I find this [link](http://blog.orastack.com/2014/05/nvd3-and-primefaces-better-charting.html) that uses the primefaces renderer.

Any other possible solutions to integrate a javascript api with primefaces?

Comment: Why you don't use method by link? I think this is a good solution.

Comment: do you mean that it's all about developping what I need in a seperate js file and then include it in the xhmtl page! no conflicts with primefaces would occur?

Comment: You extend the in built pie chart component of Primefaces. Just try and see what happened. After extend you'll use Primefaces pie component

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Do you have any useful link ?

Comment: In case I don't want to use the primefaces component,how would I do ? I don't want to mix js and java code. I 'd like to put my js apart and use the nvd3 charts..